Constant "No subject alternative DNS name" error with gradle
I have been struggling for the last day on trying to resolve an error with gradle. After deleting the .gradle/caches folder while trying to refresh dependencys, I was stuck with a No subject alternative DNS name matching objects.githubusercontent.com found. error anytime I tried to run a gradle task.
I eventually deleted my whole .gradle folder, and found that I got the same error, even as gradle was downloading. I tried flushing my dns, updating java, looking through event viewer, but coulden't find anything. Google seemed to be able to access the website fine, and even cmd was able to access it, only powershell wasn't working. I even removed, reinstalled, and updated powershell to try to get it to work, and while the curl -v for the site worked on the newer version of powershell, when I told IntelliJ to use the new version, it still didn't work. I decided to intall a repair version of windows, and while that was downloading, I also created a new user on my computer. To my suprise, this acutally worked, and I went to bed, leaving the windows update to intall overnight. The next morining, I open up my project on the new account, and get the same exact error. I have tried to update my CA Certificates, bypass ssl checking in my properties.gradle (no clue how that didn't work) and have been messing around with various settings all day.
Here is what I get when I run ./gradlew build (or any gradle command):
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.1-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching objects.githubusercontent.com found.
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:377)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:315)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1349)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1224)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1167)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:155)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1320)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1233)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:417)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:389)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2773)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2685)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1844)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching objects.githubusercontent.com found.
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:219)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:101)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:441)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:409)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:228)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:128)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1333)
        ... 26 more

Here is what I get when I run curl -v https://objects.githubusercontent.com:
* Host objects.githubusercontent.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 151.101.24.133, 199.232.36.133
*   Trying 151.101.24.133:443...
* Connected to objects.githubusercontent.com (151.101.24.133) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with objects.githubusercontent.com port 443
curl: (60) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Update: Adding a new user did not fix the problem
